# Sort HList by pattern

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

Suppose I have an hlist

```
val hlist: Boolean :: Int :: HNil = true :: 42 :: HNil
```

and I have a pattern

```
type Pattern = Int :: Boolean :: HNil
```

How can I reorder existing hlist with the pattern? I.e.

```
reorder[Int :: Boolean :: HNil](hlist) // 42 :: true :: HNil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `align` and the corresponding `Align` type class in `shapeless.ops.hlist`,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> val hlist: Boolean :: Int :: HNil = true :: 42 :: HNil
hlist: shapeless.::[Boolean,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]] = true :: 42 :: HNil

scala> type Pattern = Int :: Boolean :: HNil
defined type alias Pattern

scala> hlist.align[Pattern]
res0: Pattern = 42 :: true :: HNil
```